# Require input value if checkbox checked

Tags: angularjs

I have a series of rows with one checkbox per. With each row are several inputs. I already have validation that requires at least one checkbox in all the rows be checked. However, I am thus far unable to require the inputs have a value ONLY for the checkbox(es) checked.

[image]

**The HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<checkboxgroup-Wheelbase min-required="1">          
    <table style="width: 100%">                                
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 97%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 220px;" class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Wheelbase<br /><span style="font-weight: 400;">(choose min of 1)</span></th>
                        <th class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Payload<br />[ pounds ]</th>
                        <th class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Length<br />[ inches ]</th>
                        <th class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Height<br />[ inches ]</th>
                        <th class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Weight<br />[ pounds ]</th>
                        <th class="wheelbaseHeaderCell">Turn Radius<br />[ feet ]</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 5px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="height: 170px; overflow: auto;">
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr class="rowGroup" ng-repeat="wheelbase in wheelbases" data-rowParent="wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]">
                            <td class="wheelbaseCell" style="padding-left: 10px;" id="{{wheelbase.Id}}">
                                <!--Wheelbase-->                                    
                                <label class="checkbox" for="{{wheelbase.Id}}" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">  
                                    {{wheelbase.WheelbaseGrade}} - {{wheelbase.Inches}} inches
                                    <input ng-model="wheelbase.checked" id="wheelbase{{wheelbase.Id}}" type="checkbox"  /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <!--Payload Capacity-->
                                <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="PayloadCapacitiesCtrl">
                                    <input ng-model="payloadCapacity.Pounds" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0" ng-class="getClass({{wheelbase.Id}})" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" />
                                </span>                                                                
                            </td>                                
                            <td >
                                <!--Length-->
                                <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleLengthCtrl">
                                    <input data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0" ng-class="getClass({{wheelbase.Id}})" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"/>
                                </span>                                
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <!--Height-->
                                <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleHeightCtrl">
                                    <input data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0" ng-class="getClass({{wheelbase.Id}})" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"/>
                                </span>                                
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <!--Weight-->
                                <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleWeightCtrl">
                                    <input data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0" ng-class="getClass({{wheelbase.Id}})" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"/>
                                </span>                                
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <!--Turning Radii -->
                                <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="TurningRadiiCtrl">
                                    <input data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0"  ng-class="getClass({{wheelbase.Id}})" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"/>
                                </span>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>  
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</checkboxgroup-Wheelbase>
<span class="hint" style="margin: 0 0 0 -35px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">         
    <button style="padding-top: 5px; ;" class="addNew"  ng-click="openDialog()"><i class="icon-plus"></i> [ add new wheelbase ]</button>
</span>
```

**The directive requiring at least one checkbox be checked:**

```
.directive('checkboxgroupWheelbase', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
            var self = this;
            var ngModels = [];
            var minRequired;
            self.validate = function() {
                var checkedCount = 0;
                angular.forEach(ngModels, function(ngModel) {
                    if (ngModel.$modelValue) {
                        checkedCount++;
                    }
                });
                console.log('minRequired', minRequired);
                console.log('checkedCount', checkedCount);
                var minRequiredValidity = checkedCount >= minRequired;
                angular.forEach(ngModels, function(ngModel) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('checkboxgroupWheelbase-minRequired', minRequiredValidity, self);
                });
            };

            self.register = function(ngModel) {
                ngModels.push(ngModel);
            };

            self.deregister = function(ngModel) {
                var index = this.ngModels.indexOf(ngModel);
                if (index != -1) {
                    this.ngModels.splice(index, 1);
                }
            };

            $scope.$watch($attrs.minRequired, function(value) {
                minRequired = parseInt(value, 10);
                self.validate();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Is there a simple, elegant way to require the input fields of those checkboxes checked be required? It appears straight forward in JQuery via "rules" but I have not found a way to do this thru AngularJs. Someone suggested to me to use sub-forms but I cannot envision its implimentation.

**In Case I was not Clear Enough:**

For any row to which the respective checkbox is checked, all the inputs of that row are required to have a value. So, If the checkboxes of say rows 1,3 and 5 are checked, then the inputs of rows 1,3 and 5 require value. If a row's checkbox is checked, that same row's input require a value. If that row's checkbox is not checked, those inputs are not required. And in clearing that up, it made me think a wise thing would be for all inputs to be disabled till their respective wheelbase checkbox is checked.

**Update:**

I would like to thank user2104976  for making me think about a better user experience insofar as making sure input values are not added when the respective wheelbase checkbox is not checked, so I implemented this

```
 **"ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"**
```

in each of the respective inputs. Thanks dude!! Now how about solving my original problem, LOL!!

Comment: Hope I understood your problem correctly - For all the input fields belonging to the rows that have the checkbox in the first column checked, you wish that the input be made mandatory?

Comment: Please do not put **"SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED"** or the answer into your question... it breaks this site's strict Q & A format.  We know it's solved because we can see your answer below.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use ng-required to accomplish this:

**ng-required="wheelbase.checked"**

Here's the updated HTML's pertinent parts:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr class="rowGroup" ng-repeat="wheelbase in wheelbases" data-rowParent="wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <td class="wheelbaseCell" style="padding-left: 10px;" id="{{wheelbase.Id}}">
            <!--Wheelbase-->                                    
            <label class="checkbox" for="{{wheelbase.Id}}" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">  
                {{wheelbase.WheelbaseGrade}} - {{wheelbase.Inches}} inches
                <input ng-model="wheelbase.checked" id="wheelbase{{wheelbase.Id}}" type="checkbox" /></label>
        </td>
        <td >
            <!--Payload Capacity-->
            <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="PayloadCapacitiesCtrl">
                <input ng-model="payloadCapacity.Pounds" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" id="payload{{wheelbase.Id}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0" ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" ng-required="wheelbase.checked" ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"  />
            </span>                                                                
        </td>                                
        <td >
            <!--Length-->
            <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleLengthCtrl">
                <input ng-model="vehicleLength.Inches" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0"  ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" ng-required="wheelbase.checked" ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"  />
            </span>                                
        </td>
        <td >
            <!--Height-->
            <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleHeightCtrl">
                <input ng-model="vehicleHeight.Inches" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0"  ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" ng-required="wheelbase.checked" ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"  />
            </span>                                
        </td>
        <td >
            <!--Weight-->
            <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="VehicleWeightCtrl">
                <input ng-model="vehicleWeight.Pounds" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0"  ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" ng-required="wheelbase.checked" ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"  />
            </span>                                
        </td>
        <td >
            <!--Turning Radii -->
            <span style="display: inline-block;" ng-controller="TurningRadiiCtrl">
                <input ng-model="turningRadius.Feet" data-rowChild="{{wheelbase[wheelbase.Id]}}" type="number" style="width: 80px;" min="0"   ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked" ng-required="wheelbase.checked"  ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"  />
            </span>                                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**With ng-disabled="!wheelbase.checked"** 
[image]

**With ng-required="wheelbase.checked" &  ng-class="{'formRequire' : wheelbase.checked }"**

[image]

Here is the conditional class that kicks in to the inputs if the respective wheelbase checkbox is checked:

.ng-invalid .formRequire {
    outline: red solid 3px;
}